# Unable to connect via wired connection and getting self-assigned IP address error on Macintosh Catalina. What should I do?

Tags: macos, mac, ethernet, network

Unable to connect via wired connection and getting self-assigned IP address error on Macintosh Catalina.  What should I do?  I already restarted my fiber-optic router/modem, computer, and renewed the DHCP release.  What are some other options to fix this problem?  My Wifi still works and other devices connected to the same switch are having this problem to the main router.

[image]

Comment: *other devices connected to the same switch are having this problem to the main router.* Then the problem is not your Mac.  It's your switch and/or router.  You need to focus your efforts there.

Comment: try to put manual IP (from the same class and subnet) on Ethernet as you have in WIFI and check if you get internet or not. If yes, then check your router as Allan mentioned under the DHCP and Gateway that you have in LAN inside router.